# How to specify group in RunningValue function in SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a data set with the following fields:

```
Serialnumber, Dateofpayment, Paymentamount, Sourcecode and Campaign.
```

My data has only two campaign types, BS12 and BS13.

I'm trying to plot a running total of the payment amount by Campaign. In the chart I have the following expression for the Y value:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!PAYMENTAMOUNT.Value, SUM, "Campaign")
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> The Y expression for the chart 'Chart1' has a scope parameter that is not valid for RunningValue, RowNumber of Previous. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to the name of a containing group within the Tablix 'Chart1'.

I've looked up multiple sources and I feel like I am doing the right thing, Campaign is clearly a field in my tablix and I have entered it as a string. Why is the error occurring? - Can someone help me?

Comment: Whats your Question??

Comment: Obviously, the question is why is the error occurring?

Comment: What are the groupings you have in your chart? Do you have a `"Campaign"` grouping?

Comment: Hi, I've started a new report and added "Campaign" as a group, it now appears as table1_Campaign in the Row Groups - but the error is still occurring?? The other fields have been entered as Details.

Answer (score 3):

It's complaining about the scope parameter: "Campaign". Rather than pass the column name to the function, you need to define a group (if there is not one already) on that column in your chart and pass the name of the group instead. An example [here](http://blog.stevienova.com/2007/07/02/ssrs-runningvalue-to-get-cumulative-totals/).

Comment: Hi, I've started a new report and added "Campaign" as a group, it now appears as table1_Campaign in the Row Groups - but the error is still occurring??

Comment: You should keep `Campaign` as a column, but define a group on it. More details [here](http://popbi.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/ssrs-how-to-add-a-column-group-to-an-existing-table/).